# Filter non-Integers and them sum a 2d array

Tags: arrays, swift

Quick question. My array is thus:

```
OutsideIncome(userName: "Beth", allOthers: 0, babysitting: 0, houseCleaning: 0, mowingLawns: 0, summerJobs: 0),
OutsideIncome(userName: "Molly", allOthers: 0, babysitting: 0, houseCleaning: 0, mowingLawns: 0, summerJobs: 0)
```

One element is a `String`, and the rest are `Ints`. How would I go about getting the sum of the Ints?

Code I've tried:

**#1: FOR LOOP** - didn't work

```
for item in OutsideIncome.incomeArray.filter({ $0.userName != self.currentUserName }).reduce(0 , { $0 + $1 }) {
    tempOutsideIncome = item.allOthers + item.babysitting + item.houseCleaning + item.mowingLawns + item.summerJobs
}
```

**#2: FILTER REDUCE** - didn't work

```
let outsideIncome = OutsideIncome.incomeArray.filter({ $0.userName != self.currentUserName })
outsideIncome.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
```

**#3: FILTER** - works but is cumbersome. There has to be a simpler way.

```
let tempArray = OutsideIncome.incomeArray.filter({ $0.userName == self.currentUserName })
let tempOutsideSum = (tempArray.first?.allOthers)! + (tempArray.first?.babysitting)! + (tempArray.first?.houseCleaning)! + (tempArray.first?.mowingLawns)! + (tempArray.first?.summerJobs)!
```

I'm thinking there's some way to `map` it or `filter` `reduce` it, but I can't figure it out.

Anyone have a solution?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answer. My final code:

```
struct OutsideIncome {
    let userName: String
    let allOthers: Int
    let babysitting: Int
    let houseCleaning: Int
    let mowingLawns: Int
    let summerJobs: Int

    // create 'computed property'
    var totalJobs: Int {
        return allOthers +
            babysitting +
            houseCleaning +
            mowingLawns +
        summerJobs
    }
}

let currentUserName = "Beth"

let array = [OutsideIncome(userName: "Beth", allOthers: 1, babysitting: 0, houseCleaning: 0, mowingLawns: 0, summerJobs: 0),
OutsideIncome(userName: "Molly", allOthers: 0, babysitting: 0, houseCleaning: 0, mowingLawns: 0, summerJobs: 0)]

let result = array.filter({ $0.userName == user.firstName }).reduce(0, { $0 + $1.totalJobs })
}
```

Comment: I'd go by creating first a computed property for `OutsideIncome` that is all the others ints added. Seems that you may use that var quite often, so why not create it. Then, you'd work on only one property, and do simpler things (there should already be sample of that), like `let total = filteredArray.flatMap{$0.totalIncome}`, where filteredArray is your `tempArray` (third test of yours).

Comment: The way it's set up, I have to have the `String` in the array along with the `Ints`. Is there a way to filter out the `String` and leave only the `Ints`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a computed property

```
    var totalJobs: Int {
    return allOthers +
        babysitting +
        houseCleaning +
        mowingLawns +
    summerJobs
}
```

Then you can chain filter and reduce

```
let result = array.filter { $0.userName ==  currentUserName}.reduce(0) { (res, item) -> Int in
return res + item.totalJobs
```

}

Comment: I don't quite understand your code. I get an error when I enter it in that says `use of unresolved indentifier "all others"`. How exactly am I supposed to use the computed property?

Comment: Wow. Super cool. It worked. And I just learned something new: **computed properties!** Thanks!!

Comment: No problem @PhontaineJudd
Have a nice day!